# Grizzly, sharing spring generated context

Tags: spring, jersey, grizzly

I have a standalone spring project and i need to start an embedded rest service with it.
I could be able to start the server with grizzly, my problem is, when i start grizzly server, it creates its own application context. so the instances created by my parent application is not accessible through the REST service.

Is there anyway of sharing the parent application's context between Grizzly server and parent application, other than getting grizzly generated application context.

This is my code for starting the grizzly server.

```
public class RemotingServer {

    private HttpServer httpServer;
    private String host;
    private int port;

    public RemotingServer(String host, int port) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void init() throws Exception {
        URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://" + host + "/").port(port).build();

        ResourceConfig rc = new DefaultResourceConfig();

        ConfigurableApplicationContext cac =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:remoting-context.xml");

        IoCComponentProviderFactory factory = new SpringComponentProviderFactory(rc, cac);

        httpServer = GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(uri, rc, factory);
        httpServer.start();

    }

    public void stop() {
        httpServer.stop();
    }
}
```

I tried setting current context as `cac`'s parent too. Then i got following exception.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext`

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext cac =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:remoting-context.xml");
// Have Spring load the context
cac.refresh();
IoCComponentProviderFactory factory = new SpringComponentProviderFactory(rc, cac);
```